# Ruby on Rails Autotest No Longer Catching Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest

I am going through Hartl's rails tutorial and the autotest is no longer running newly written tests. I write a new test and it will not be reflected in autotest. Autotest still runs and remains green with a set number of examples. Existing tests will fail if I change things but new test are not recognized. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Caught it. I had an errant end keyword.